# How do I convert Objective-C array of pointers to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsarray, swift3

In `Objective-C` these are two declarations of array of pointers:

```
NSArray<MTKMesh *> *mtkMeshes;
NSArray<MDLMesh *> *mdlMeshes;
```

I am struggling declaring the equivalent in `Swift 3.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MTKMesh` and `MDLMesh` are *classes* (reference types). A variable
of type `MTKMesh` in Swift is a reference to an object instance,
i.e. what a variable of type `MTKMesh *` is in Objective-C.

Therefore you can simply declare

```
var mtkMeshes: [MTKMesh] = []
var mdlMeshes: [MDLMesh] = []
```

Each element of the array is a reference to an object instance:

```
let mesh1 = MDLMesh()
let mesh2 = MDLMesh()
mdlMeshes.append(mesh1)
mdlMeshes.append(mesh1)
mdlMeshes.append(mesh2)

print(mdlMeshes[0] === mdlMeshes[1]) // true
print(mdlMeshes[0] === mdlMeshes[2]) // false
```

The first two array elements reference the same object instance, the
last array element references a different instance.
(`===` is the ["identical-to" operator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1538988)).

Comment: Thanks Martin. In your Swift equivalent I notice you have pre-allocated the arrays which is actually different then the Obj-C. For context, this is a snippet from code that uses mdlMeshes as an inout param to a function that allocates and populates that array. +1 for the '"===" tip.

Comment: @dugla: You can also declare `var mtkMeshes: [MDLMesh]?` and pass its address to a function `func foo(meshes: inout [MDLMesh]?)` which allocates and populates the array.